# $(A \cup B)' = A' \cup B'$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A,B \subset X$, where $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space. I wanna prove that $(A \cup B)' = A' \cup B'$, where $A'$ is the derived set of $A$.

**Proof**:

- $A' \cup B' \subset (A \cup B)'$.
  Indeed, knowing that $A \subset A \cup B$ implies $A' \subset (A \cup B)'$ and $B \subset A \cup B$ implies $B' \subset (A \cup B)'$, then $A' \cup B' \subset (A \cup B)'$
- $(A \cup B)' \subset A' \cup B'$ (this second part is where I'm not so sure of my proof).
  Indeed, if $x \in (A \cup B)'$, then $\forall U \ni x$ open, we have that $U \backslash \{x\} \cap (A \cup B) = (U \backslash \{x\} \cap A) \cup (U \backslash \{x\} \cap B) \ne \emptyset$.
  So $U \backslash \{x\} \cap A$ or $U \backslash \{x\} \cap B$ must be $\ne \emptyset$, that is $A' \cup B' \ne \emptyset$.
  So $x \in A' \cup B'$, then $(A \cup B)' \subset A' \cup B'$

**Edit**:
Based on the insight from Arturo Magidin, I modify my second argument with:
So $U \backslash \{x\} \cap A$ or $U \backslash \{x\} \cap B$ must be $\ne \emptyset$:

- if $U \backslash \{x\} \cap A \ne \emptyset$, then $x \in A'$
- if $U \backslash \{x\} \cap B \ne \emptyset$, then $x \in B'$

In either case, $x \in A' \cup B'$

Comment: For the second part: we know that the union of (finitelhy many) closed sets is finite. $A\subseteq A’\cup B’$, $B\subseteq A’\cup B’$, so $A\cup B\subseteq A’\cup B’$. But $A’\cup B’$ is closed, so....

Comment: For *your* argument... I don’t understand why you say “that is $A’\cup B’\neq\varnothing$” (you don’t know that is nonempty, so why are you asserting it is nonempty? And why does it matter?)

Comment: Arturo. In your first comment. The union of finitely many closed sets is closed (instead of finite?).

Comment: @PeterSzilas: Yes; but too late to edit. Thanks!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I've thought that since $U \backslash \{x\} \cap A \ne \emptyset$ or $U \backslash \{x\} \cap B \ne \emptyset$, if the first one is true then the whole condition is equal to ask that $x \in A'$, if the second is true then the whole condition is equal to ask that $x \in B'$, in either case $x \in A' \cup B'$

Comment: @FedericBelotti: But that is not what you said. What you sad was just “$A’\cup B’$ is not empty”. That’s an assertion of fact that as it happens *could be incorrect* (what happens if $A$ and $B$ are both empty? Your entire argument begins from a false premise, $x\in (A\cup B)’$, which is fine because the implication will be true, but here you are making an assertion of fact which is not only potentially false, but also utterly irreleavant). If you meant that a *specific element* is in $A’\cup B’$, then say **that**, don’t say “this is not empty”.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for the explanation. I want to ask you if my previous comment is right

Answer (score 1):

$x \not \in A' \cup B'\implies \exists U_{A},U_{B}$ open sets containing $x$ such that
$(U_{A}-{x})\cap A =\phi=(U_{B}-{x})\cap B  \implies ((U_{A}\cap U_{B})-{x})\cap (A \cup B)=\phi$.

Clearly $(U_{A}\cap U_{B})$ is an open set containing $x$.
So we have got an open set (say $U=(U_{A}\cap U_{B})$) containing $x$ such $(U-{x})\cap (A \cup B)=\phi$. Hence $$x \not \in (A \cup B)'$$.

Therefore $(x \not \in A' \cup B'\implies x \not \in (A \cup B)') \implies(A \cup B)' \subset A' \cup B'$