# Theorem 23.4 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, connectedness

> Let $A$ be a connected subspace of $X$. If $A\subseteq B\subseteq \overline{A}$, then $B$ is also connected.

**My attempt:**

**Approach(1):** Assume towards contradiction, $B$ is not connected. Then $\exists P,Q\in \mathcal{T}_B$ such that $P,Q\neq \phi$, $P\cap Q=\phi$, and $P\cup Q=B$. Let $P=B\cap R$ and $Q=B\cap S$, where $R,S\in \mathcal{T}_X$. Since $P,Q\neq \phi$, $\exists x\in P=B\cap R$ and $\exists y\in Q=B\cap S$, $x\neq y$, because $P\cap Q=\phi$. Since $x\in R$ and $y\in S$, we have $R\in \mathcal{N}_x$ and $S\in \mathcal{N}_y$. So $x,y\in B\subseteq \overline{A}$. By definition of closure, $A\cap R\neq \phi$ and $A\cap S\neq \phi$. Both $A\cap R$, $A\cap S\in \mathcal{T}_A$. Since $P\cap Q=B\cap (R\cap S)=\phi$, we have $(A\cap R)\cap (A\cap S)=A\cap (R\cap S)\subseteq B\cap (R\cap S)=\phi$, inclusion follows from the hypothesis $A\subseteq B$. Hence $A\cap R$ and $A\cap S$ is disjoint set. $P\cup Q =B\cap (R\cup S)=B$. Which implies $A\subseteq B\subseteq (R\cup S)$. So $(A\cap R)\cup (A\cap S)=A \cap (R\cup S)=A$. Hence union of $A\cap R$ and $A\cap S$ is $A$. Thus $A\cap R$ and $A\cap S$ form a separation of subspace $A$. Which contradicts our initial assumption that $A$ is connected. **Is this proof correct?**

**Approach(2):** Assume towards contradiction. Let $P$ and $Q$ be the separation of $B$. By lemma 23.2, $A\subseteq P$ or $A\subseteq Q$. WLOG, assume $A\subseteq P$. Since $P$ is closed in $B$, $(\overline{A})_B$(Closure in $B$)$\subseteq P$, by property of closure set. Note $(\overline{A})_B=\overline{A}\cap B$, $\overline{A}$ denote closure in $X$. Since $B\subseteq \overline{A}$, we have $\overline{A}\cap B=B\subseteq P$. We already know $P\subseteq B$. Thus $B=P$. So $P\cup Q=B\cup Q=B$ which implies  $Q=\phi$. Thus we reach contradiction. This proof is slight variation of Munkres’ proof. **Is this proof correct?**

**Approach(3):** (Munkres’ Proof) Assume towards contradiction. Let $P$ and $Q$ be the separation of $B$. By lemma 23.2, $A\subseteq P$ or $A\subseteq Q$. WLOG, assume $A\subseteq P$. By exercise 6 section 18(a) (link: [Exercise 6, Section 17 of Munkres’ Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4349334/861687)), $B\subseteq \overline{A} \subseteq \overline{P}$. Since $P$ is closed in $B$, $(\overline{P})_B=P=\overline{P} \cap B$. So $P\cap Q= (\overline{P}\cap Q)\cap B$. Since $(\overline{P}\cap Q)\subseteq Q\subseteq B$, we have $P\cap Q= (\overline{P}\cap Q)\cap B=\overline{P}\cap Q=\phi$. Thus $\overline{P}\cap Q=\phi$. $B\cap Q\subseteq \overline{A} \cap Q\subseteq \overline{P}\cap Q=\phi$. Which implies $B\cap Q=\phi \Rightarrow Q=\phi$. Which contradict our initial assumption. **Is this explanation correct?** Munkres didn’t explicitly go into the subspace details. In this approach, I tried to fill in the details.

At first glance Munkres’ proof looks fine, but it’s not the “complete” proof(IMO), I didn’t realise this thing at first.

**Edit:** Better version of approach(3) is the following: $B\subseteq \overline{A} \subseteq \overline{P}$. So $B\subseteq \overline{P}$. $B\subseteq \overline{P} \cap B=(\overline{P})_B=P$, since $P$ is closed in $B$. Thus $B\subseteq P$, which implies $Q=\phi$. We reach contradiction.

Comment: Just my opinion, but I think if you put the problem you're trying to solve in the question title rather than where it can be found in your textbook, more people will recognise it as something they can help you with :)

Comment: use \emptyset or \varempty instead of \phi for the empty set in MathJax or LaTeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts as of now are notationally dense and a bit of work to follow. I suggest the following approach if you want to use a separation type argument: Show that $B$ is disconnected if and only if there are closed (in B), non-empty, disjoint subsets of $B$ that union to $B$. Using this, if you assume $B$ is not connected, show that $A$ must lie completely in one of the closed (in B) sets which union to $B$. You will be able to find a closed set containing $A$ that is a subset of $\overline{A}$, which contradicts the fact that $\overline{A}$ is the smallest closed subset containing $A$.

Taking some inspiration from Henno Brandsma's [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44850/locally-constant-functions-on-connected-spaces-are-constant/44938#44938) about locally constant functions, we present a proof based on the following characterization of connectedness:

A topological space $X$ is connected if and only if for every open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ there is a chain in $\mathcal{U}$ between any two points in $X$ (Henno Brandsma defines these terms in the post linked above).

**Proof** (that $A\subseteq B\subseteq \overline{A}$ and $A$ connected implies $B$ connected):

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $B$ and fix $x,y\in B$. There are four cases:

**Case 1:** $x$ and $y$ are in $A$. In this case, there is a chain in $\mathcal{U}$  between $x$ and $y$ as $A$ is connected.

**Case 2:** $x$ is in $A$ and $y$ is not in $A$. In this case, $y$ is a limit point of $A$. Since $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $B$, then there exists an open set $U\in\mathcal{U}$ containing $y$. As $y$ is a limit point of $A$, then there exists a $z\in U\cap (A\setminus\{y\})$. By connectedness of $A$, there is a chain in $\mathcal{U}$ from $x$ to $z$. Link $U$ to the end of the chain from $x$ to $z$ to get a chain from $x$ to $y$ in $\mathcal{U}$.

**Case 3:** $x$ is not in $A$ and $y$ is in $A$. This case is similar to **Case 2**.

**Case 4:** $x$ and $y$ are not in $A$. I will leave this as an exercise to you.

This completes the proof that $B$ is connected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I’m not familiar with some term used in proof yet. I’ll google it. Anyway, this approach is such a clever(not necessarily easiest) way to prove this theorem. I never thought of this approach for obvious reasons.

Comment: This is 220 IQ level solution.

Comment: Case(4): $x,y\in A’$. Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $B$. Since $B=\bigcup \mathcal{U}$, $\exists U,V\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\in V$. So $U\in \mathcal{N}_x$ and $V\in \mathcal{N}_y$. Since $x,y\in A’$, we have $\exists r\in U\cap (A-\{x\} )\neq \emptyset$ and $\exists s\in V\cap (A-\{y\} )\neq \emptyset$. Since $A$ is connected and $r,s\in A$, $\exists$ a chain $T=\{U_1,….U_n\}$ from $r$ to $s$. Then $T’=\{U, U_1,…,U_n,V\}$ chain from $x$ to $y$, since $r\in U\cap U_1 \neq \emptyset$ and $s\in U_n \cap V\neq \emptyset$. Is it right?

Comment: @user264745 yes, nice proof. good job :)

Comment: How did you first thought of using this(chain) definition of connectedness?

Comment: @user264745 i saw Henno Brandsma use it in his proof linked in my answer. I was curious to see if a proof using chain connectedness would work, and it did!

Comment: how a proof using chain connectedness worked, not if

Comment: I was skimming through James Dugundji book. In chapter 5 section 1 problem 8(a) this(chain) definition of connectedness is given.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give my favourite proof: let $f: B \to \{0,1\}$ be continuous (where the codomain is discrete). Then $f\restriction_A$ is continuous and by connectedness of $A$, $f[A]=\{i\}$ for some $i \in \{0,1\}$. As $f$ and the constant function with value $i$ coincide on the dense subset $A$ and $\{0,1\}$ is Hausdorff, we have that $f \equiv i$ and so $B$ is connected.
Or use that by continuity $f[B]\subseteq f[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}=\overline{\{i\}}=\{i\}$ instead, of you prefer.

This uses the standard alternative definition of connectedness of $X$ by saying $X$ is connected iff every continuous $f:X \to \{0,1\}$ must be constant. (Sketch of proof: if it were non-constant, then $f^{-1}[\{0\}$ and $f^{-1}[\{1\}$ would form a separation of $X$ and if $A \cup B$ is a non-trivial separation into two disjoint open sets, we can define $F \equiv 0$ on $A$ and $1$ on $B$ to find a non-constant $f$, as required). I like such proofs better than messing with separations.

Comment: @user264745 It's trivial to prove yourself. No reference needed.

Comment: $f$ is defined on $B$ and $B\subseteq \overline{A}$. So writing $f(\overline{A} )$ is legit?

Comment: How? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @user264745 Just use $f[B]=f[\overline{A}^{(B)}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}$ so relative closure, if you prefer.. The Hausdorff codomain argument from the line before remains unchanged. $A$ is still dense in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

All approaches in your answer seem to be correct, but to be honest: They get bogged down in details and are too complicated. Henno Brandsma's proof is most elegant and transparent, but let me nevertheless give a short proof based on separation. It is similar to approach 2.

So let $P, Q$ be a separation of $B$. By lemma 23.2, $A\subseteq P$ or $A\subseteq Q$. WLOG, assume $A\subseteq P$. Noting $(\overline{A})_B=\overline{A}\cap B = B$, we get $B \subseteq P$ since $P = B \setminus Q$ is closed in $B$. Since $P \subseteq B$, we see that $P = B$. This contradicts the assumption that $P, Q$ is a separation of $B$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah, $P=B$ is enough to show contradiction. In approach(2), I showed(unnecessary, depends on who is reading) why $P=B$ contradicts our assumption of $P,Q$ is separation of $B$.